# Find a date that falls with in a given range

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on date manipulation in the following scenario.

> Inputs  : DateA ,DateB ,Month_count
>
> Precondition : DateB is always greater than DateA

```
Output: 
1)I need   to find newstartdate and newEndDate from DateB 
newStartDate<DateA<newEndDate.
2)For newstartDate  ,dateB is subtracted by month count .
3)NewEndDate is newStartDate+month_count.
4)Repeat 2,3 until the  condition 1 becomes true.
```

I have come up with while condition to perform this.Is there any way to simplify this logic?

```
  Declare @dateA datetime 
  Declare @dateB Datetime 
  declare @month_count int
  declare @newstartdate datetime
  declare @newenddate datetime

  set @dateA= '2013-02-21'
  set @dateB='2013-08-23' 
  set @month_count=3

  SET @newstartdate=DATEADD(mm,-@month_count,@dateB)
  Set @newenddate=DATEADD(mm,@month_count ,@newstartdate)

   WHILE Not (@newstartdate < @dateA  AND  @dateA<@newenddate)
   BEGIN
     SET @newstartdate=DATEADD(mm,-@month_count,@newstartdate) 
     Set @newenddate=DATEADD(mm,@month_count,@newstartdate)
     Select @dateA 'DateA',@newstartdate '@newstartdate',@newenddate '@newenddate'
  END
```

Comment: On a complete side note, I would recommend always writing dates as strings in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` as that will remove any cultural issues

Comment: Thanks .Modified the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by simple.

I was thinking about how to do it with a recursive CTE, but Johan got there first. That's probably the right way to do it.

However, it isn't necessarily as "simple" as what you had. Yours can be simplified a bit little further.

BTW, I also recommend becoming consistent in how you use capitalize in your SQL and you variables. Regardless of the style you choose it easier to read and looks "better" if it at least internally consistent.

```
Declare @dateA datetime 
Declare @dateB Datetime 
declare @month_count int
declare @newstartdate datetime
declare @newenddate datetime

set @dateA= '2013-02-21'
set @dateB='2013-08-23' 
set @month_count=3

Set @newenddate=@dateB
SET @newstartdate=DATEADD(mm,-@month_count,@dateB) 

WHILE Not (@newstartdate < @dateA  AND  @dateA<@newenddate) BEGIN
   Set @newenddate=@newstartdate
   SET @newstartdate=DATEADD(mm,-@month_count,@newstartdate)      
END
--do you need to select the interimediate results or simply the final?
Select @dateA 'DateA',@newstartdate '@newstartdate',@newenddate '@newenddate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this helps?

```
declare @dateA datetime = '2013-02-21'
declare @dateB datetime = '2013-08-23' 
declare @month_count int = 3

;with dates(newstartdate, newenddate)
as
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(month, -@month_count, @dateB)
            ,@dateB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(month, -@month_count, newstartdate)
            ,newstartdate
    FROM    dates
    WHERE   newstartdate > @dateA
)
SELECT  TOP 1 * 
FROM    dates
ORDER BY newstartdate
```

Comment: Getting expected results.Will be useful to incorporate these logic   as a single query. I will have to check which one is easy to handle in coding bewtween these 2 options (cte or while loop coding.)